# getting the selected TEXT in select list and saving it in session

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a select List which is based on a LOV and the LOV is based on a query, the query is calling a function and gets the LOV. The select list Item itself, stores the ID of the row which is selected but I want the TEXT of the row that is selected to be stored in session so I can access it in my print query in shared components.

i can get the text of selected row of select list by running `$("#P952_CODING option:selected").text();` but this just shows the text and when I created a (SET VALUE dynamic action) on the selectlist item and gave it the js expression and as affected element I gave it another Item It didn't work and the new item remained null.what elese can be done?

Comment: Rewrite that "print query" so that it takes the select list item's ID value and selects the TEXT value from the same table (function?) that is used to populate the LoV.

Comment: tnx man I'll try that.